# How Can I Call To An Object, When It Is Lower In the Code (Java)

Tags: java

How Can I Call To An Object, When It Is Lower In the Code (Java)

This is an Example:

```
class examp {
int i = 8;
void test() {
if(L.i == M.i)System.out.println("Hello!");
}
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
examp L = new examp;
examp M = new examp;
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work about your code?  what errors are you getting?

Comment: What wasn't clear about my answer the last time?  You need to pass a reference to an object to use it.  Variables are not named globally.

Comment: They are global if you declare them as instance variables.

Comment: Why Are You Capitalizing Every Word In Your Question?

Comment: I do understand you don't want downvotes, but please edit your post so Every Word Isn't Capitalized As It's Somewhat Hard To Read.

Comment: Its not that it wasnt clear i just dont understand it! lol, i still dont, like i said i am COMPLETE beginner!

Comment: Ok so, im trying to use an object that i made in the main class, but i can not use it unless it is made inside of the class which it is referenced to, which gives me a stackoverflow error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
class Example {
    int i = 8;
    static void test(Example l, Example m) {
        if(l.i == m.i)
           System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example l = new Example();
        Example m = new Example();
        Example.test(l, m);
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Peter! You Are Awesome, thx for taking the time to reply!

Comment: Why are you using two classes?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 The formatting suggested main() was not in the examp or Example class

Comment: I Did Not End Up Using The Static Keyword Due To My Level Of Java Programming(beginner) I just created a separate class with the same methods and variable's, this worked out fine for, me so anybody who is trying to do the same thing as me, and space doesn't necessarily concern you, just create a separate class!

Answer (score 2):

You must send those variables as parameter to your test method.

```
class examp {

    int i = 8;

    public static void test(examp L, examp M) {
        if (L.i == M.i) {
            System.out.println("Hello!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        examp L = new examp();
        examp M = new examp();
        test(L, M);
    }
}
```

Comment: "new examp;" is not going to compile. And how about using proper indentation?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `L` and `M` as instance variables. Declare them outside of methods. YOu may need to make them `static`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to help ;)

void test() become static void test(examp L, examp M).

int i = 8 become int i;

when you instance your objects in main you must assign the value of i, in two ways
L.i = 8;
M.i = 10;

or
build a specific constructor where you pass the value of i

Finally in your main call examp.test(L, M).

P.S. By convention name of object have capitol letter.  exam become Exam

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class examp {
    int i = 8;
    void test(examp other) { // your test needs parameters
        if(this.i == other.i)
            System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        examp L = new examp(); // <-- need ()'s
        examp M = new examp();
        L.test(M);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Examp{
    int i = 8;

    void test(){
        // here L and M are undefined
        if(L.i == M.i) System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Examp L = new Examp();
        Examp M = new Examp();
        // L and M are visible only here
    }
}
```

You can do something like that:

```
class Examp{
    int i = 8;
    Examp L;
    Examp M;

    void test(){
        // here L and M are visible
        if(L.i == M.i) System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        L = new Examp();
        M = new Examp();
    }
}
```